# sum column if column name matches with keyword sql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have records from the table based on expenses, earnings, and transaction date based on each month entry in the system.

My query is working fine but I have some scenario to extend this query.

I have a column named `description`. What I need to do in my query is, if `description=='deposit'` so it should sum all the `amounts` based on `description=='deposit'` for each month.

Example:

I have deposited 25000 in jan, then 3455 in feb, then again 34566 in feb so on and so forth for each month.

Here is my query but it is not filtering for each month:

```
SELECT
    MONTH (transaction_date),
    SUM(amount) AS total_amount,
    (SELECT SUM(amount) as deposit FROM tbl_finanace WHERE description = 'Deposit'),
    SUM(IF(amount < 0, amount, 0)) AS expenses,
    SUM(IF(amount > 0, amount, 0)) AS earning,
    transaction_date
FROM
    `tbl_finanace`
WHERE
    transaction_date LIKE '%2015%'
AND user_id = '15'
GROUP BY
    MONTH (transaction_date)
ORDER BY
    MONTH (transaction_date)
```

Comment: You can do the same as other `SUM(case when description = 'Deposit' then amount else 0 end) AS expenses,`

Comment: Yes your statement solved it. great.

Comment: Let me add as an answer then it might help others too.

Comment: Yes, sure you have to add it as answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation could be done as below using the conditional sum

```
SUM(case when description = 'Deposit' then amount else 0 end) AS deposit
```

Comment: Very very well pick and great catch. :) I cant believe how i missed it. Well, was waiting for your response on this question. @AbhikChakraborty thank you very much.. great guy.. you have solved it.